# $P(X\leq x) = P(X<x)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given a continuous random variable $X$, is it correct to assume that its *cdf* $P(X\leq x)$ is equal to $P(X < x)$?

In discrete random variables, I know that that it is important but not really sure for the case of continuous functions.

Comment: Hint: $P(X=x) = 0$

Comment: Thank you! I think this hint should be marked as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just note that $P[X\leq x] = P[X<x]+P[X=x]$ and that the last probability is zero.